# Eclipse juno can not open with error " An error has occurred. See the log file",ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, eclipse

I'm trying to launch Eclipse for the first time. I have downloaded the package and installed it manually When i launch it i get an error. Here is the log file :

```
 !SESSION 2012-10-10 16:06:11.460 -----------------------------------------------
        eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
        java.fullversion=GNU libgcj 4.6.3
        BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
        Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

        !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-10-10 16:06:19.756
        !MESSAGE Could not start bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
        !STACK 0
        org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not start bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:217)
           at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:297)
           at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.12)
           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
        Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.console.command.adapter.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.console.
           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:215)
           ...7 more
        Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Activator.start() of bundle org.apache.felix.gogo.command.
           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
           at org.eclipse.equinox.console.command.adapter.Activator.startBundle(Activator.java:248)
           at org.eclipse.equinox.console.command.adapter.Activator.start(Activator.java:239)
           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(libgcj.so.12)
           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
           ...11 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.felix.gogo.command.OBR
           at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.12)
           at org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Activator.start(Activator.java:54)
           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(libgcj.so.12)
           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
           ...19 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.Repository
           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.12)
           at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.12)
           ...23 more
        Root exception:
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.felix.gogo.command.OBR
           at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.12)
           at 

        !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.433
        !MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.433
        !MESSAGE Bundle com.sun.el_2.2.0.v201108011116 [4] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 com.sun.el 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.el_2.2.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 com.sun.el 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.5.0.
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Bundle javax.el_2.2.0.v201108011116 [6] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 javax.el 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_2.5.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 javax.el 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.5.0.
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Bundle javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016 [8] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 javax.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))".
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Bundle javax.servlet.jsp_2.2.0.v201112011158 [9] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 javax.servlet.jsp 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.el_2.2.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 javax.servlet.jsp 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 javax.servlet.jsp 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 javax.servlet.jsp 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))".
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955 [21] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.jasper.glassfish 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.el_2.2.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.jasper.glassfish 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.jasper.glassfish 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.descriptor_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.jasper.glassfish 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.jasper.glassfish 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.jsp_2.2.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.jasper.glassfish 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.jsp.el_2.2.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.jasper.glassfish 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.jsp.tagext_2.2.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.jasper.glassfish 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package javax.tools_0.0.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.jasper.glassfish 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))".
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.0.v20120522-1841 [91] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.434
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_[2.6.0,4.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_[2.6.0,4.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.0.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.http_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.util_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.util.component_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.util.log_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry_1.1.200.v20120522-2049 [92] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_2.3.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.3.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.300.v20120522-1841 [93] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_[2.3.0,3.1.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package javax.servlet.annotation_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package javax.servlet.descriptor_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.435
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_[2.3.0,3.1.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.400.v20120522-2049 [94] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_[2.4.0,3.1.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package javax.servlet.annotation_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package javax.servlet.descriptor_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_[2.4.0,3.1.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.jsp_[2.0.0,2.3.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.jasper.servlet_[0.0.0,6.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20120522-2049 [95] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_0.0.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_2.4.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.4.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20120717-130216 [135] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.help.webapp 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.100.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.help.webapp 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry_1.0.200.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.help.webapp 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_2.4.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.help.webapp 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.436
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.4.0.
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core_1.0.400.v20120522-1651 [139] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.tool_0.0.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch_0.0.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model_0.0.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.util_0.0.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))".
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt_1.0.500.v20120522-1651 [141] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.tool_0.0.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))".
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool_1.0.101.v20120522-1651 [142] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))".
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.continuation_8.1.3.v20120522 [155] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.continuation 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.continuation 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.mortbay.log_[6.1.0,7.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.continuation 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.mortbay.util.ajax_[6.1.0,7.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.http_8.1.3.v20120522 [156] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.http 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.http 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.http 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.437
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.io_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.http 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.438
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.438
        !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.io_8.1.3.v20120522 [157] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.io 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.438
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.util_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.io 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.438
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.util.component_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.io 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.438
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.util.log_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.io 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.438
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.438
        !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522 [158] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.438
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.438
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.438
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.http_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.438
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.438 org.eclipse.jetty.jmx_8.0.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.439
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.security_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.eclipse.jetty.util_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.eclipse.jetty.util.component_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.eclipse.jetty.util.log_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.util_8.1.3.v20120522 [161] was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.util 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.util 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.6.0.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.util 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.slf4j_[1.5.0,2.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.util 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.slf4j.helpers_[1.6.0,2.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.util 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.slf4j.impl_[1.5.0,2.0.0).
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.util 2 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.440
        !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.slf4j.spi_[1.6.0,2.0.0).

        !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-10-10 16:06:30.441
        !MESSAGE Application error
        !STACK 1
        java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
           at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.ConstructorRequestor.calcDependentObjects(ConstructorRequestor.java:79)
           at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.getDependentObjects(Requestor.java:143)
           at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveArgs(InjectorImpl.java:408)
           at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:312)
           at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:240)
           at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
           at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:420)
           at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:434)
           at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:182)
           at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
           at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
           at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
           at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
           at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
           at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
           at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
           at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
           at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
           at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.12)
           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

would you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

At UbuntuForums there's a [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12237067)  with a similar problem. You can try the fix given there by [lucacerone](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12240616&postcount=3):

> 1. close eclipse
> 2. open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T)
> 3. type: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java`

Comment: thanks,but for me it does not work! any other suggestions ? :(